# auto-complete follow link on select

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Here is the fiddle (directive at bottom):

http://jsfiddle.net/swfjT/249/

Instead of logging on click of input / enter, how would I make clicking an auto-complete item from the dropdown direct to a link, say `/#/name/:name`? Haven't been able to find anything that does this.

Basically, click on Oscar to redirect.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery UI's autocomplete plugin triggers a [`select`](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-select) callback when "... an item is selected from the menu".

This callback function receives `event`and `ui` params. The `ui` params contains a reference to selected item, which easily enables you to construct the redirect you are seeking for:

```
angular.module('MyModule', ['ui.keypress'])
  .directive('autoComplete', function($timeout, $location) {
    return function(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
      iElement.autocomplete({
        source: scope[iAttrs.uiItems],
        select: function(event, ui) {
          var path = '/#/name/' + ui.item.value;
          console.log('redirecting to', path);
          $location.url(path);
          return false;
        }
      });
    };
});
```